# Is it safe to split the disk partition I installed Ubuntu on?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk, storage, boot-partition

When I installed Ubuntu,I made a disk partition of 120 GB, which of course is too much as I don't have many heavy weight software. I'm currently using only 16/120GB, I was wondering if I can split the partition on which Ubuntu(Make the 120GB to 50 GB and separate the 70GB partition) is installed and if I do so I won't have any bad consequences.

Comment: Yes, but only from a live system, as the partition to resize should not be mounted. Boot from a live usb and run `gparted`. I would still stick with a single partition....

Comment: @pLumo I also have windows installed, is it safe to do this from windows then?

Comment: nore sure if windows tools can handle ext3/ext4 partitions or whatever your file system is... But if they can handle them, yes, sure.

Comment: I'll just do it from the live disk then

Comment: make sure to backup important files ;-)

Comment: Will do that ...

Comment: Windows disk management will not manipulate ext3/ext4 partitions